# Drag and drop for Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Hey guys, I was wondering if there are any good drag and drop plugins for Prototype. I'm well aware of the great drag and drop plugin available for jQuery, but I'm looking for a plugin for Prototype. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First [result](http://www.google.com/search?q=prototype%20drag%20and%20drop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on Google

Comment: Asked by "Anonymous" with 1 rep, lol

Comment: @Samo, SO intends to be a central place for programmers to find answers to questions about programming. If "use the google" were an appropriate response, this site would be gutted.

Comment: @Kirk, SO intends to be a central place for programmers to find answers to questions about programming. If "use the google" were an appropriate response, this site would be gutted. And unless you think that "Anonymous" is trying to do something nefarious (and asking a simple question isn't nefarious), what difference does their "name" or "reputation" have in the quality of the question? If you don't find the question interesting, just move on. Edit: and 138 reputation ain't much to brag about.

Comment: @eyelidlessness I'm not bragging :P ..and really? Is there zero criteria to post here?? :|

Comment: @Kirk, of course there's criteria for posting here, and if you're not sure what they are maybe you should search for them ;) but no, whether an answer is found on Google is not one of those criteria.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: your point is fair but don't you think that programmers should learn to search for answers before they start asking other developers? I don't think any damage was done by suggesting a little searching, even if it was done sarcastically. I've never cried about it on occasions when other geeks have dealt with me this way and I doubt Anonymous will go curl up in a ball either. In my experience, we're not the type to baby people.

Comment: @Samo, I think the damage done is that the questioner and other people reading the comments here might be discouraged from asking more questions, weakening SO and making their ability to answer their questions more difficult. I'd much rather wade through "boring" questions than people feel their questions aren't "good enough".

Comment: @Samo (cont'd from last comment…) Furthermore, for better or worse I assume that questioners *have* searched already; since the vast majority of SO traffic comes from Google, it's a safe bet. And for that matter, if you go back and listen to SO's creators' rationale for SO, they explicitly *defend* **deliberately** asking questions whose answers duplicate Google search results, in order to promote the wiki aspect of SO. I'm not crying over the suggestions to Google, just discouraging further misuse of SO by those doing it.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: it doesn't discourage anyone from asking quesitons, it *encourages* them to search before asking, which they should if they wish to be independent developers. I also typically assume that a user has searched before asking, but in this case, it was blatantly obvious that the user did not. If I would have had to do extensive searching to find the answer to this question, that would be different. When it's the first result on Google, seriously, give me a break.

Comment: @Samo, **AGAIN**, SO **encourages** people to post questions even if the answer is easily found, assuming all other criteria for an appropriate question are met. By penalizing people for doing just that, and by telling them that they shouldn't, you are discouraging them from using SO for what it's here for: to be a central place where programming answers can be found. Google isn't the beginning nor the end of the web.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: ok you win buddy

Comment: @Samo gimme a +1 then! Didn't u delete ur answer which was just like mine?? lol

Answer (score 3):

Scriptaculous

Official site: http://script.aculo.us/

Example of Drag/Drop: http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/draggable/